# Webfonts don't work in Firefox Developer Edition 54.0a2

Tags: html, css, firefox, webfonts

I have two webfonts in my CSS file; one font and one icon font. In Chrome, Firefox and Internet Explorer everything works perfectly fine, but Firefox Dev Edition 54.0a2 gives me a ton of errors (for the font, not for the icon font) in the console:

```
downloadable font: Layout: Lookup flags require GDEF table, but none was found: 8 ... source: ....woff  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup 0 ... source: ....woff  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: GSUB: Failed to parse lookup list table ... source: ....woff  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer ... source: ....woff  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: Layout: Lookup flags require GDEF table, but none was found: 8 ... source: ....ttf  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: Layout: Failed to parse lookup 0 ... source: ....ttf  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: GSUB: Failed to parse lookup list table ... source: ....ttf  style.css:18:86235
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer ... source: ....ttf
```

What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: Stop using Dev-edition? Seriously, dev-edition is not really that much used - why are you bothering with it?

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I'm not sure, but won't these features/bugs be in coming versions of Firefox? Because then it is important.

Comment: Normally, no. Dev edition is not the same as nightly build.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie okay, thank you
**EDIT:** the bug also exists in nightly.

Comment: Which font is it? It might just be an error in the font, which might happen on any version with proper error-correction/checking implemented. I would suggest looking into using either another font, or remaking the font you need.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie it was Futura Condensed. Using another font would not be possible, as this font is like the "brand font". Thankfully, using another generator just worked.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it, just used [Font2Web](http://www.font2web.com/) instead of FontSquirrel.

Answer (score 0):

I was still having this issue on Firefox Nightly 122.
To fix this just go to: "**about:config**", search for "**down*font**" and set

> gfx.downloadable_fonts.otl_validation

to **false**